# removing last 4 characters in a file with python

Tags: python, string

I have a code that creates a file according to a string. However, if i create a file without, for example, ".txt" at the end, it makes a generic file.

I say, ok, and I put ".txt" to the end of the name. It creates a .txt, but with the name being  "Whatever I typed.txt" as well as the ".txt" extension.

I want my program to remove ".txt", or the last 4 characters, from the name.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Are you using some GUI library's file-save dialog? If so, which one? (And which platform?) If not, what exactly does "I say, ok" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use String splitting:

```
filename = "whatever.txt"
filename_without_extension = filename[:-4]
```

Or use `os.path.splitext` which gives a tuple containing filename and extension:

```
path.splitext(filename)
```

This would give you `('whatever', '.txt')`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the last four characters from a `str`:

```
name = name[:-4]
```